# Active Directory passing password

Tags: c#, active-directory

I working with an API with Active Directory Authentication.

I'm using this string to connect when the active directory is off.

```
    mc.addPasswordParam("password", "Imnottellingyou");
```

But I can't seem to find out how to pass my active directory password. Anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could give some details about the specific API that you're using.  There's really no way for us to help you if you don't provide enough details.

Comment: Homemade API using XML, XML Schema and JSON.

But that's besides the point. I'm not asking about the API itself.. 

I want to know how to replace "Imnottellingyou" with my active directory password. 

Its fairly useless if i hard coded it. I would know if i was a proper C# developer but I'm more a Database guy

Comment: Active Directory authentication *doesn't* work by just having the password passed around. It's an entirely different way of doing things (the protocol is known as [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))) So there's no programmatic mechanism to magically obtain the password.

Comment: arh right.. so i can't just call it from some pre-existing method! 

I didn't want to but, That's cool then I will add a password box to my application. 

Thanks for the help @Damien_The_Unbeliever ! Not possible is an answer too.